# Where is nodes for altering the strength of the sun?

Tags: node-editor

Where is "use nodes" for altering the strength of the sun?  I saw it at one point and it seems to have disappeared.

Comment: in Cycles Render you can either find it in the Node Editor or in the Properties panel > Data > Nodes > Strength

Answer (score 1):

Just go into the node editor with the lamp selected and turn on USE NODES in the settings. If it is already toggled check for a emission node where you can up the strength. Hope it helped mate!